# Linkbutton Not working in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

In the below code i have link button inside datagrid when i click linkbutton it is not opening a popup window in chrome whereas in IE and mozilla it is working fine.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
 <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="From Quote" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                            <ItemTemplate>                                              
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkQuote" runat="server" CommandName="Quote" Text="Quote" />
                            </ItemTemplate>        
                          </asp:TemplateColumn> 

 if (e.CommandName.Equals("Quote"))
                {
  Label KK = (Label)dgPOD.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TXT1");
                    Label lbl = (Label)dgPOD.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("LBL1");
                    str1 = KK.Text.ToString();
                    str2 = lbl .Text.ToString();

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopUp", "ShowPopUp()", true);
                }
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript error? Is the script rendered on the page? Does calling ShowPopUp() from console in chrome work?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code. it will work fine.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
       /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-TextLayoutMetrics" content="natural" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

If helpful then please vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding surrounding script-tags

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopUp", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">ShowPopUp();</" + "script>", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowPopUp", "ShowPopUp()", true);
```

Comment: You should add some explainations otherwise your answer can be deleted caused by low quality.

Comment: Sorry! My English is not very well.

Comment: You should try it :) You can receive more up votes and similar. :)